# How to switch to a Stack Exchange account?

Tags: discussion, login, accounts

I am aware additional logins (Facebook, Google, Yahoo...) can be added to stack by going to:

- My logins
- Add more logins

I find no option here to add a Stack Overflow login.

[image: Login options screen]

**Question**

If I create a new Stack Overflow login can it replace my existing login (currently Google)?

*If not*

What is the process to transfer a login to use Stack Overflow as primary?

**Note:** I use a Google login to access Stack Overflow and am about to delete my Google account.

How can I maintain access to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Do you mean Stack *Exchange* login? Because that's possible.

Comment: See the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials

Comment: What do you see if you visit this page - http://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent

Comment: I did read the help centre before posting this however as I mentioned above I find no option here to add a stackoverflow login.

Comment: Again - I ask do you mean "Stack **Exchange**" login, because there is no Stack **Overflow** login option.

Comment: If there is no stackoverflow login then I guess so. Currently I login on stackoverflow.com. I have seperate logins for each stack exchange site and can login and out of them individually.

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704.